# bpython : pastebin error

Tags: python, bpython

I'm using [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) and on F8 I'm getting this following 301 error:

```
Upload failed: <ProtocolError for bpaste.net/xmlrpc/: 301 Moved Permanently
```

Why does it routes to /xmlrpc/ ?
Is there another way around in the console to be able to use the pastebin? 
Python 2.7.6
Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

Comment: I have updated my post. Also I'm new, I'm just exploring in order to adapt bpython but I found this error when I pressed down F8

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought it was a coding problem, but instead it seems to be about your interactive IDE failing to push information to pastebin. What version of bpython are you using?

Comment: It's ok! I'm using this version `bpython version 0.12 on top of Python 2.7.6
(C) 2008-2012 Bob Farrell, Andreas Stuehrk et al. See AUTHORS for detail.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the bpython documentation:

pastebin_url

The pastebin url to post to (without a trailing slash). This pastebin has to be a pastebin which uses LodgeIt. Examples are: http://paste.pocoo.org/xmlrpc/ and http://bpaste.net/xmlrpc/ (default: http://bpaste.net/xmlrpc/)

The pocoo.org pastebin is retired, so you can't use that.  The default, bpaste.net, is returning a 301 error.

## curl -I http://bpaste.net/xmlrpc/

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 04:56:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Location: https://bpaste.net/xmlrpc/

OK, so update your pastebin_url to use https, right?

## curl -I https://bpaste.net/xmlrpc/

HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND

The problem you're having is that bpaste.net is no longer supporting the LodgeIt /xmlrpc/ url.  Maybe this is only temporary, or maybe they've retired the public xml interface.

The solution would be to find another LodgeIt pastebin that you can use, or setup your own.

I don't know of any other public LodgeIt pastebins; maybe there are some.  A google search turned up this HowTo:

http://killyourtv.i2p.us/howtos/pastebin/

Comment: thks adalle! I will try the #bpython irc channel to know more about bpaste.net or If I could use gist(https://gist.github.com/) instead.